# Using Cramers rule with the Eigen library

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I am using the Eigen linear algebra library and I would like to solve a 3x3 matrix.  In the past I have used Cramer's rule.  Does anyone know if I can use cramer's rule in Eigen or will I need to program that myself?

I am using C++ 11 and Linux.  I cannot use any other external libraries, like BOOST etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use `eigen`. Take a look at the documentation here

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html

The example given is quite short and simple:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <Eigen/Dense>
> using namespace std;
> using namespace Eigen;
> int main()
> {
>    Matrix3f A;
>    Vector3f b;
>    A << 1,2,3,  4,5,6,  7,8,10;
>    b << 3, 3, 4;
>    cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
>    cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
>    Vector3f x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
>    cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
> }
> ```

Output:

> ```
> Here is the matrix A:
>  1  2  3
>  4  5  6
>  7  8 10
> Here is the vector b:
> 3
> 3
> 4
> The solution is:
> -2
>  1
>  1
> ```

It is almost guaranteed to work faster than a hand-made solver using Cramer's rule.

Comment: Yes, I missed that.  Thanks I will check this out.

Comment: Np. PS: For future reference, it's a good idea to leave questions unanswered for a  at least a little while (e.g. a day or two). You (and those who stumble upon this later) might get better answers that way.